# Most efficient way to write over file after reading

Tags: perl, file-io

I'm reading in some data from a file, manipulating it, and then overwriting it to the same file.  Until now, I've been doing it like so:

```
open (my $inFile, $file) or die "Could not open $file: $!";

    $retString .= join ('', <$inFile>); 
    ...

close ($inFile);

open (my $outFile, $file) or die "Could not open $file: $!";

    print $outFile, $retString;

close ($inFile);
```

However I realized I can just use the truncate function and open the file for read/write:

```
open (my $inFile, '+<', $file) or die "Could not open $file: $!";

    $retString .= join ('', <$inFile>); 
    ...
    truncate $inFile, 0;
    print $inFile $retString;

close ($inFile);
```

I don't see any examples of this anywhere.  It seems to work well, but am I doing it correctly?  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to read an entire file contents is to (temporarily) set the *input record separator* `$/` to `undef`, after which the next `readline` will return all of the rest of the file. But I think your original technique is much clearer and less involved than just reopening the file for write.

Note that all the following examples make use of the [`autodie`](https://metacpan.org/pod/autodie) pragma, which avoids the need to explicitly test the status of `open`, `close`, `truncate`, `seek`, and many other related calls that aren't used here.

Opening in read/write mode and using truncate would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Fcntl 'SEEK_SET';

my ($file) = @ARGV;

open my $fh, '+<', $file;
my $ret_string = do { local $/; <$fh>; };

# Modify $ret_string;

seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;
truncate $fh, 0;
print $fh $ret_string;
close $fh;
```

whereas a simple second open would be

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($file) = @ARGV;

open my $fh, '<', $file;
my $ret_string = do { local $/; <$fh>; };

# Modify $ret_string;

open $fh, '>', $file;
print $fh $ret_string;
close $fh;
```

There is a third way, which is to use the equivalent of the *edit-in-place* `-i` command-line option. If you set the built-in variable `$^I` to anything other than `undef` and pass a file on the command line to the program then Perl will transparently rename by appending the value of `$^I` and open a new output file with the original name.

If you set `$^I` to the empty string `''` then the original file will be deleted from the directory and will disappear when it is closed (note that Windows doesn't support this, and you *have* to specify a non-null value). But while you are testing your code it is best to set it to something else so that you have a route of retreat if you succeed in destroying the data.

That mode would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$^I = '.old';

my $ret_string = do { local $/; <>; };

# Modify $ret_string;

print $ret_string;
```

Note that the new output file is selected as the default output, and if you want to print to the console you have to write an explicit `print STDOUT ...`.

Comment: `readfile` --> `readline`.  Although without `$/`, the effect would be reading the file.

Comment: @JimDavis: Thanks. Brain problems anticipating the rest of the sentence!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [`$INPLACE_EDIT`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = '...';

local @ARGV = $file;
local $^I = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    # Modify the line;
    print;
}
# unlink "$file$^I"; # Optionally delete backup
```

For additional methods for editing a file, just read [perlfaq5 - How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f).

Answer (score 1):

I would change the way you're reading the file, not how you open it. Joining lines is less efficient than reading whole file at once,

```
 $retString .= do { local $/; <$inFile> };
```

As for `truncate` you might want to seek to begining of the file first as [perldoc suggests](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html)

> The position in the file of FILEHANDLE is left unchanged. You may want to call seek before writing to the file.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie::File) module may help if you are changing some lines in a file.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @source, 'Tie::File', 'file.txt' or die $!;

for my $line (@source) {
   # Modify $line here      
}

untie @source;
```